# Django - aggregation zero

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got the following in my views.py :

```
called = CashFlow.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).filter(type='cashin').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

distributed = CashFlow.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).filter(type='cashout').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

try:
   result = round(-distributed/called * 100,2)
except ZeroDivisionError :
   result = 0
```

Everything works fine as long as one of the queries return something. but, let's say there haven't been any cashouts so far -> the result should be zero. However, I receive the following Typerror : "bad operand type for unary -: 'NoneType'"

How can I solve this?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your try/except:

```
if distributed is None:
    distributed = 0
```

Or add `or 0` after the CashFlow query:

```
distributed = (CashFlow.objects
    .filter(item__slug=itemslug)
    .filter(type='cashout')
    .aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']) or 0
```

Do the same with `called`.

Comment: Even simpler: `if not (called and distributed): result = 0`, i.e. if any of the aggregates is None or 0, the result is 0 (if this is what you want). In the else clause you put the actual calculation. Then you can even save the try/except.

Answer (score 1):

Add `TypeError` to your exceptions in `except`

```
try:
   result = round(-distributed/called * 100,2)
except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError) as e :
   result = 0
```

Comment: thanks. this one works as well but in my specific case - I'm not going into details - the solution from Endre works best ! but thanks again for the help and effort !